# Tensorflow equivalent of PyTorch NLLLoss

Tags: python, tensorflow

is there a tensorflow built in equivalent of PyTorchs Negative-Log-likelihood function?

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a tensorflow built in equivalent of PyTorchs Negative-Log-likelihood function?

Yes:

- [`tensorflow.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy)
- [`tensorflow.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossEntropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy)
- [`tensorflow.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) (which is used in the former)

Comment: SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy is what I was looking for, however pytorch also divides by the amount of class afterwards. This needs to be done in addition in TF.

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure now, some values seems to be close but different.

Comment: It seems like pytorch's NLL loss takes log-probabilities, whereas tensorflow takes probabilities.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't able to find tf function that doesn't fuse softmax https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2462